# String to become a Variable in bash

Tags: bash

I've written this language free as i'm not 100% sure how to do it in bash.

I'd like to take an array like the following:

```
array=('address'=> '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '22')
```

And then access the array key as a variable in bash like so:

```
$address=127.0.01
echo $address

127.0.0.1
```

Thanks.

Comment: `address=127.0.0.1; var="address"; echo ${!var}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you need [associative arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).  These need to be explicitly declared with `declare -A`:

```
$ declare -A array
$ array[address]=127.0.0.1
$ array[port]=22
$ key=address
$ echo ${array[$key]}
127.0.0.1
$ key=port
$ echo ${array[$key]}
22
$ echo ${!array[@]}
address port
$ echo ${array[@]}
127.0.0.1 22
$
```

You can also assign multiple elements at once:

```
$ array=([address]=127.0.0.1 [port]=22)
$
```

You can iterate over the associative array:

```
$ for key in ${!array[@]}; do
>     echo "key=\"$key\", array[$key]=\"${array[$key]}\""
> done
key="address", array[address]="127.0.0.1"
key="port", array[port]="22"
$
```

Note associative arrays are only available in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version 4.0 or greater.